# Why optimizer doesn't use an index (sql server)

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

SQL Server 2016.

```
Table1 is (Col11, Col12, Col13)
Table2 is (Col21, Col22, Col23)
```

Col11 and Col21 are respective PKs, both indexes are clustered.
Col22 references Col11 and is indexed.
Col12 is indexed as well.

Query:

```
SELECT count(*)  
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.col22 = t1.col11
WHERE t1.col12 = <value>
```

The execution plan uses the index on col12, but does not use an index on col22 (it uses a different index from Table2, on a column that's not even a part of the query). 
This is true for both plans that use either hash or nested loops joins.

What is a potential reason for this behavior and how it can be addressed?
Both tables are ~100 million rows, selectivity rate on t1.col12 is about 2%.

For those who wanted a script:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1 (
  Col11 BIGINT IDENTITY (1,1),
  Col12 BIGINT, 
  Col13 VARCHAR(100)
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.Table2 (
  Col21 BIGINT IDENTITY (1,1),
  Col22 BIGINT, 
  Col23 INTEGER
)

ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1 ADD 
  CONSTRAINT PK_Table1 PRIMARY KEY (
    Col11 ASC
  ) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
          SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF,
          ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)

ALTER TABLE dbo.Table2 ADD
  CONSTRAINT PK_Table2 PRIMARY KEY (
    Col21 ASC
  ) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
          SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
          ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)

ALTER TABLE dbo.Table2 WITH NOCHECK ADD
  CONSTRAINT FK_Table2_Table1 FOREIGN KEY(Col22)
    REFERENCES dbo.Table1 (Col11)
    ON DELETE CASCADE

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Table1_1 ON dbo.Table1 (Col12 ASC)
  WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
        SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF,
        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Table2_1 ON dbo.Table2 (Col22 ASC)
  WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
        SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF,
        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Table2_2 ON dbo.Table2 (Col23 ASC)
  WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
        SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF,
        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
```

Comment: Please don't use old style joins

Comment: Is your problem with performance? Or you are wondering about sql servers execution plan?

Comment: it is the performance. it takes about 12 seconds to complete on a pretty good hardware. with the join removed, it takes a fraction of a second. with that said, i am only interested in the answers to the question itself and not general optimization (partitioning, re-indexing et cetera).

Comment: Can you post actual CREATE TABLE / CREATE INDEX commands so that people can reproduce? This is much better than vaguely describing the tables and indexes...

Comment: What's the selectivity of col22? And are the values (at least somewhat) evenly distributed?

Comment: Without the table and index definitions we are left guessing.

Comment: Hi James, yes, they are. There will be 10 to 20 entries in Table2 per each entry selected from Table1.

Comment: Aaron/Sean - done

Comment: You take a sub-set of `table 1` (based on `col12 = value`) and then count the number of records in `table 2` that match said sub-set via `col22=col11`, right? Probably the system assumes that running over the chosen index (that likely includes `col22`??) is the least expensive approach to count how many rows of `table 2` will 'survive' the match against the subset of `table1`. That said, what happens if you force the index to the one on `col22`? (I'd expect that one to be the least expensive approach too, but hey, don't underestimate the optimizer). Also, are your statistics up-to-date?!?

Comment: Hi deroby, Yeah, stats are up-to-date. For my model i made all the indexes really basic (stripped pretty much down to the bone), no include clauses et cetera. if I force an index on col22, it does use it, and the execution time is faster. It's still quite slow because of the millions of nested loops, but faster than hash join between col23 and col11 and makes my client somewhat happy. The thing is the query is in a view, and this view is used across multiple SPs and I don't want to put the index hint in. Thank you for the idea.